# using BASH how can i replace all text between two patterns containing forward slashes?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that replaces text in a text file between two patterns "opt/" and "/".
An example of the data in the file is:

```
daw9udiwa9diuoawdj098awd89a0909w  opt/TEXTTOREPLACE/app-data/version.txt
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/TEXTTOREPLACE/app-data/package.txt
awdhaw9d8yawdf8uaw9f8uwafhiuhawf  opt/TEXTTOREPLACE/bin/somefile/somefile
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/TEXTTOREPLACE/bin/someapp/somefile
```

I've looked at using  the 'sed' command, but the pattern matching is confusing me.

I have tried:

```
sed -e 's!\/[^\/]*\/!\/CHANGE TO ME\/!'
```

This works - but I would like to add in the "opt" at the beginning to minimise errors

So I tried the following with no luck

```
sed -e 's!opt\/[^opt\/]*\/!opt\/CHANGE TO ME\/!'
```

I will be using a $VAR to replace text
so for example

```
VAR=CHANGED
sed -e 's!opt\/[^opt\/]*\/!opt\/$VAR\/!'


output:
daw9udiwa9diuoawdj098awd89a0909w  opt/CHANGED/app-data/version.txt
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/CHANGED/app-data/package.txt
awdhaw9d8yawdf8uaw9f8uwafhiuhawf  opt/CHANGED/bin/somefile/somefile
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/CHANGED/bin/someapp/somefile
```

help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have several `/ .... /` in your lines. What determines which of those needs to be replaced?

Comment: "opt/" is the first match then the next "/"
id like to replace any text between the above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues with the current `sed` code:

- to expand OS variables the `sed` script must be wrapped in double quotes
- the use of `!` as a delimiter may cause issues with some shells and/or shell configurations (eg, `!` is a common shorthand for accessing the command line history)
- escaping the `/` is only needed when the `/` also serves as the `sed` script delimiter (ie, no need to escape `/` if using a different delimiter)

One `sed` idea that addresses these issues:

```
sed -e "s|opt/[^/]*|opt/$VAR|" input.txt
```

Where:

- `opt/[^/]*` - match on the string `opt/` plus all characters that are not a `\`
- `opt/$VAR` - replace with the string `opt/` plus the contents of the OS `VAR` variable

This generates:

```
daw9udiwa9diuoawdj098awd89a0909w  opt/CHANGED/app-data/version.txt
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/CHANGED/app-data/package.txt
awdhaw9d8yawdf8uaw9f8uwafhiuhawf  opt/CHANGED/bin/somefile/somefile
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/CHANGED/bin/someapp/somefile
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to using `awk` rather than `sed`, the following may work for you:

```
$ awk -v rep="CHANGED" -F/ 'BEGIN{OFS="/"} {$2=rep; print}' file1 
daw9udiwa9diuoawdj098awd89a0909w  opt/CHANGED/app-data/version.txt
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/CHANGED/app-data/package.txt
awdhaw9d8yawdf8uaw9f8uwafhiuhawf  opt/CHANGED/bin/somefile/somefile
wdalkwhjf8aufwaoif98fawfojaw98f8  opt/CHANGED/bin/someapp/somefile
```

Split each line on the forward slash character and replace the second field with your desired replacement text.  Then format the output with the output field separator (OFS) set as a forward slash.

Comment: No need to escape the `/` in `-F`